# How to replace everything with blank after question mark in a string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace everything with blank after question mark.

Suppose I have a string like below:

```
var str = "/root/Users?SkillId=201;"
```

Now I want to replace everything with blank after `?`.

Expected output: `"/root/Users"`

I tried below solution:

```
var str = "/root/Users?SkillId=201;".replace(/[^? ]/g, "");
console.log(str); // output : ?

str = str.split('?')[0] // though worked but not readable
```

I don't want to use for loop for this. Isn't there is any better way to do this?

Comment: Replace everything with blank (space), or delete everything?

Comment: This one `str = str.split('?')[0]` is fair enough

Comment: @DavidConrad:Yeah delete everything after question mark

Comment: What do you mean `str = str.split('?')[0]` isn't readable?

Comment: Also, it appears you mean delete the question mark and everything after it, not delete everything after the question mark. Sorry, but precision is important in programming.

Comment: Downvoter please give me reason for downvoting.What wrong did you find with this question please tell me so that i can remember this while asking further questions on SO :)

Comment: @Albzi actually i thought there may be performance problem with split as it is creating 2 string and it doenst look readable also

Comment: I don't know enough to know whether regex or split is faster, but I'll admit I think that `split('?')[0]` is more readable than `replace('/\?.*$/g,"");`

Comment: You  mean you want to _remove the query string_, for which there must be literally millions of examples on Google?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Based on my research i have  provided something in my code in which 1 option didnt workout and i was just not sure about 2nd option from performance point of view that is why i have ask question here for sake of getting better answer which i got.Can you tell me why did you downvoted this question??

Comment: I already told you: lack of sufficient research effort. There is no need for another question on this topic - it has been answered millions of times. This is a Q&A, not a helpdesk. Cheers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : its not that i didnt put my sufficient efforts for the research but it is just that i didnt get it what i was trying to search.May be it will require alittle bit of time to specialize in this kind of research as nobody knows everything from the start.It takes time and everything comes from an experience as learning is a continous process.Anyways thank you i will keep your valuable suggestion in my mind :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should help

```js
var str = "/root/Users?SkillId=201;"

str = str.replace(/\?.*$/g,"");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: This worked.Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and please keep helping like this.Appreciated :)

Comment: This works even if there isn't a question mark in the input string (it would just leave it unaltered). Other solutions may error if run on an input without a question mark.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to get the substring before the '?':

`str = str.substr(0, str.indexOf('?'));`

Answer (score 3):

Match the content before `?`

```js
var str = "/root/Users?SkillId=201;"
var a = str.match(/(.*)\?/);

console.log(a[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use JavaScript function

```
var str = "/root/Users?SkillId=201;";
var str = str.substring( 0, str.indexOf("?")-1 );
console.log(str);
```

here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ahmednawazbutt/2fatxLfe/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "/root/Users?SkillId=201;"
var parts = str.split('?', 2);
```

`parts[0]` contains string before '?'

Answer (score 1):

### A solution without using a **Regular Expression**;

#### Pseudocode

```
Find the index location of the '?' character,
    if the resulting index is greater than -1; then;
        extract the new string; starts at index 0 to the
        nth index location of the '?' character
```

#### JS Code

```
// get the index of the first occurrence of '?'
var qMarkIndex = str.indexOf('?'); 

// '?` character exist
if(qMarkIndex > -1)
    str = str.substr(0, qMarkIndex);

console.log(str);
```

Adding a conditional statement that checks if the `?` character exists ensures that; if for some reason the `str` doesn't contain the `?` character then the string stays the same.